# Combining two SELECT WHERE statements

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to query two tables from a MS SQL server 2014 database where I have read-only access.

The caveat being, I need to combine the results of two similar SELECT WHERE statements in a single output:

```
SELECT     Item, Price, Element, Time
FROM       Goods, Goods, RoutingLine, RoutingLine    
WHERE      Goods.Routing IS NOT NULL 
AND        Goods.Routing = RoutingLine.Routing
AND        RoutingLine.Element= 'Machine%'

SELECT     Item, Price, Element, Time
FROM       Goods, Goods, RoutingLine, RoutingLine    
WHERE      Goods.Routing IS NOT NULL 
AND        Goods.Routing = RoutingLine.Routing
AND        RoutingLine.Element= 'Operator'
```

The desired output should be something along those lines:

```
Item | Price | Element (machine) | Time (machine) | Element (operator) | Time (operator)
```

I am currently at a loss on how to proceed, maybe a temporary table?
But I am not even sure it can be used with just db_reader access.

Edit: as requested here are some mockup tables

**GOODS**

```
ITEM (unique) | PRICE | ROUTING
Bananas       | 12.22 | RTBanana01
Apples        | 10.00 | RTFruit01
Peaches       | 17.15 | RTPeach01
Pears         | 32.19 | RTFruit01 
Kiwi          | 02.19 | 
Cherries      |       | RTFruit02
Mangoes       |       | RTMango01
Oranges       |       |
```

**ROUTINGLINES**

```
ID (unique) | ROUTING    | ELEMENT    | TIME
0001        | RTBanana01 | Machine 01 | 5.12
0001        | RTBanana01 | Overhead   | 0.30
0003        | RTBanana01 | Setup      | 1.00
0004        | RTBanana01 | Operator   | 5.12
0005        | RTFruit01  | Machine 03 | 8.20        
0006        | RTFruit01  | Overhead   | 0.30  
0007        | RTFruit01  | Operator   | 4.10            
0008        | RTPeach01  | Machine 01 | 6.10      
0009        | RTPeach01  | Setup      | 1.50
0010        | RTFruit02  | Setup      | 3.50
0011        | RTMango01  | Operator   | 1.75
0012        | RTMango01  | Overhead   | 4.75
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ITEM (unique) | PRICE | MACHINE    | MC TIME | OPERATOR | OP TIME
Bananas       | 12.22 | Machine 01 | 5.12    | Operator | 5.12
Apples        | 10.00 | Machine 03 | 8.20    | Operator | 4.10
Peaches       | 17.15 | Machine 01 | 6.10    |          |
Pears         | 32.19 | Machine 03 | 8.20    | Operator | 4.10 
Cherries      |       |            |         |          |
Mangoes       |       |            |         | Operator | 1.75
```

Comment: Can you try self-join?

Comment: Your existing queries are almost certainly wrong. Learn to use explicit join syntax by denting yourself the use of commas in thr from clause. This will enforce better joins.

Comment: Can you add sample records for each of the tables and show us the output you would expect that sample to generate?  Can you explain why `Goods` and `RoutingLine` each appear twice in the from clause?  It's also worth mentioning that you should look into moving from the old join syntax to the [new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Comment: Updating the post with table examples

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both using "AS" to identify the tables.

A simpler example for the situation:

If you had:

```
SELECT     Item, Time
FROM       Goods, RoutingLine    
WHERE      Goods.Routing = RoutingLine.Routing
AND        RoutingLine.Element= 'Machine%'
```

and:

```
SELECT     Item, Time
FROM       Goods, RoutingLine    
WHERE      Goods.Routing = RoutingLine.Routing
AND        RoutingLine.Element= 'Operator'
```

you can combine it to:

```
SELECT     G1.Item, R1.Time, R2.Time
FROM       Goods AS G1, RoutingLine AS R1, Goods AS G2, RoutingLine AS R2     
WHERE      G1.Routing = R1.Routing
AND        G2.Routing = R2.Routing
AND        R1.Element= 'Machine%'
AND        R2.Element= 'operator'
AND        G1.Item = G2.Item
```

(suppose Goods.Item is unique key)

Comment: I̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶S̶E̶L̶E̶C̶T̶ ̶m̶i̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶G̶2̶.̶I̶t̶e̶m̶?̶ Nevermind

Comment: @M.Baroni no. G1.Item and G2.Item are equal and you want it just one time in the result table.

Comment: It seems that this method does not handle items that have no associated Machine% and/or Operator entries nicely. Ideally i would like to have them listed with the corresponding column empty. Edited my example dataset/output to make it clearer